# Error during npm start/expo start on expo reactive native Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to run react native expo, it installed (via '`npm install -g expo-cli`') globally and I created Project ('`expo init react-project`') and works fine. But i wend inside folder and run `npm start` / `expo start` , appears Errors as shown in picture. I also get Error on '`expo`'.
I also deleted node_modules Folder and reinstall it (`npm install`) but didn't help.
Like you can see in Images, I have latest node,npn and Git versions. And its strange that , although I have installed expo globally, i get expo version on E:\ but not in subfolder (detail in screenshots).

Could anybody help me out?

- Error on `expo`:
  [image: Error on expo]
- Error on `npm start` / `expo start`:
  [image: Error on npm start / expo start]
- Latest Versions:
  [image]

Comment: check if you are in the correct folder

Comment: Do you have expo installed locally in the project? It seems like it may be clashing. Expo should be installed globally and not be listed in your package.json. Also, do you have a directory named "1"? I'm guessing not, but if you do that won't work with expo

Comment: Expo is installed globally and i do not have directory named "1". its strange why this error is coming. .